# Can't set a new resolution on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, multiple-monitors, xrandr

Okay, I've been using my laptop connected with a external screen which is 2560x1080, try to add the new resolution and set up. But always return `xrandr: Configure crtc 1 failed`. Also checked my CPU max resolution on HDMI and it's 4096 x 2304@60Hz, don't know what else to do.
The commands I use was: `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --crtc 1 --mode 2560x1080_60.00`, `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --crtc 2 --mode 2560x1080_60.00`, `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --mode 2560x1080_60.00` but always return failed.

Its weird cause it shows 2560x1080 in the GUI, but still don't set for the 2560x1080, always reverse.[Resolutions options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xESYF.png)